# How to set different images for every cell in uiTableView.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have tableView and i want to set the different image for every cell in my tableView based of certain condition but i am getting the image of last satisfied condition for all cells.

here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]; 
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2; 

if (self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.datePickerArray objectAtIndex:1])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.serverResponseArray count]; i++)
        {
            if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqual: @"workshop"])
            {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"workshops.png"];
            }
            if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqual: @"keynote"])
            {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"keynote.png"];
            }
            if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqual: @"panel"]|| [[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_topic" ] isEqual: @"WISNET"])
            {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pannel.png"];
            }
            if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqual: @"social"] || [[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_topic" ] isEqual: @"RWW"])
            {
                cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"social.png"];
            }


        }
       cell.textLabel.text =  [[self.globalSessionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

Expected output:
[image: i am expecting output something like this (ignore the content of cells.)]

output i am getting:

[image: i am getting output something like this (ignore the content of cells.)]

Comment: remove that for loop from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and user indexPath.row to get the index

Comment: I am going to suggest you two things here: First use `else-if` lader if there's any possibility to execute one condition at once. Then Check by setting breakpoints if your conditions is being satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill your `UITableViewCell` content in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method. And to compare 2 `NSString` use `isEqualToString:` method.

EDIT:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]; 
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    if (self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.datePickerArray objectAtIndex:1])
    {
        for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.serverResponseArray count]; i++)
        {
            NSString* session_type = [[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_type"];
        if([seesion_type isEqualToString: @"workshop"])
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"workshops.png"];
        else if([session_type isEqualToString: @"keynote"])
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"keynote.png"];
        else if([session_type isEqualToString: @"panel"]|| [[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_topic" ] isEqualToString: @"WISNET"])
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pannel.png"];
        else if([session_type isEqualToString: @"social"] || [[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"session_topic" ] isEqual: @"RWW"])
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"social.png"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text =  [[self.globalSessionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: how to use that tableView method. any example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in your code it will always return `i = 0;`

maybe you can try something like:

```
       if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqualToString: @"workshop"])
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"workshops.png"];
        }
        if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqualToString: @"keynote"])
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"keynote.png"];
        }
        if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqualToString: @"panel"]|| [[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"session_topic" ] isEqualToString: @"WISNET"])
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pannel.png"];
        }
        if([[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"session_type" ] isEqualToString: @"social"] || [[[appDelegate.serverResponseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"session_topic" ] isEqualToString: @"RWW"])
        {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"social.png"];
        }
```

Comment: By using this m getting output of the first condition.

Comment: updated my code maybe you can try again. changed isEqual to isEqualToString

Comment: tried again. this also doesn't make any effect. stil same output.

Comment: maybe you should check the condition to validate the result. try putting break points to it

Answer (score 1):

replace `isEqual:` by `isEqualToString:`

Comment: did that. output is coming for first satisfied condition. not what i am expecting.

Comment: i think you should debug line by line

Comment: seems ok, could you tell me which condition it is going and showing orange got always?

Comment: okay. i am going to debug now line by line and then i will reply here.

Comment: made some small changes in logic and condition and finally got the expected output

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30068/discussion-between-vaibhav-saran-and-zac24)

Answer (score 0):

Use `isEqualToString:` for string comparison

Comment: how does that gonna make any effect.?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure if (self.pickerSelectedRow == [self.datePickerArray objectAtIndex:1]) is satisfied every time?

Also why are you comparing value [self.datePickerArray objectAtIndex:1] with self.pickerSelectedRow value?